# The resource object with key 'KeyName' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I am developing a multilingual `ASP.NET` website using the `App_GlobalResources`.
In `App_GlobalResources` folder, I added two resource files:
`Resource.language.en-US.resx` and `Resource.language.fr-FR.resx`.

I also added a web form named `About.aspx`.
In this page I added this span:

```
<span>
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource.language, aboutFoundation%>" />
</span>
```

And in code behind:

```
public partial class About : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["lang"] = "en";
    }
}
```

And last, the `BasePage`:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["lang"]))
        {
            Session["lang"] = Request["lang"];
        }
        string lang = Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]);
        string culture = string.Empty;
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("en") == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            culture = "en-US";
        }
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("fr") == 0)
        {
            culture = "fr-FR";
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
}
```

Now when I run the project, I get the following error:

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. Parser
>   Error Message: The resource object with key 'aboutFoundation' was not
>   found.

What could be the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a file named `Resource.language`. You have a `Resource.language.en-US.resx` and a `Resource.language.fr-FR.resx`. So you can either add one more file in your `App_GlobalResources` folder named: `Resource.language.resx` And it's content should be exactly the same as `Resource.language.en-US.resx` or you can rename `Resource.language.en-US.resx` to `Resource.language.resx` so you would have one `Resource.language.resx` that is necessary.

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. And if I rename the Resource.language.en-US.resx to Resource.language.resx, when I use the english language, it will take the values from this same folder?

Comment: @Hanady...I personally prefer to have three resource file when I'm creating  multilingual sites.

Comment: yep. This is what I did. Thanks!