# Multilanguage WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, globalization, multilingual, culture

I'm working  multi-language (Arabic & English) 
WPF application with resources in two different files (Resources.en-GB & Resources.ar-LY), 
I declared a new method in the app.xaml

```
public void LanguageSwitcher(string _currentUICulture)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
                                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(_currentUICulture);
    }
```

In the **MainWindow** and after Initialize Component I put

```
((App)Application.Current).languageSwitcher("ar-LY");

        this.FlowDirection =
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft ?
                FlowDirection.RightToLeft :
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
```

In the language switcher button, I call the method and pass the en-GB culture that I want

```
((App)Application.Current).languageSwitcher("en-GB");
```

**The Problem**: When I hit the language button to change UI to English, The culture changed and the window flow direction changed to LeftToRight **BUT** the text does not change, It seems that the **Resources.en-GB** does not load!

What I miss here?!

Comment: This might helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/33803265/2946329

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload every label component after changing the culture.
You can try to open new window after changing the culture and check that the created components are changed.